# Same Jetty code, different number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jetty, redhat

We are running same Jetty service on two servers but are seeing different number of threads created by both services (50 vs ~100 threads).

Both servers are running identical Java code on RedHat5 (they do have slightly different kernels). Yet Jetty on one of the servers creates more threads than the other one. How is it possible?

Comment: Don't think you'll get good answers without a little context; could you show the code in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread counts are dynamic, depends on many many factors.

The number of threads that you see at any one point can vary greatly, based on hardware differences (number of cpu cores, number of network interfaces, etc), kernel differences, java differences, load differences, active user counts, active connection counts, transactions per second, if there are external dependencies (like databases), how async processing is done, how async I/O is done, use of http/2 vs http/1, use of websocket, and even ${jetty.base} configuration differences.

As for the counts you are seeing, 50 vs 100, that's positively *tiny* for a production server.  Many production servers on moderately busy systems can use 500 (java) threads, and on very busy commodity systems its can be in the 5,000+ range.  Even on specialized hardware (like an Azul systems devices) its not unheard of to be in the 90,000+ thread range with multiple active network interfaces.